# Vectors for simulations

Tags: r, vector, simulation

The code I have so far is written below. This is simulation so there is no actual data. I have two questions:

1. I have two vectors (treat and cont) but I need to put them into one single vector which I did (vect), however, I need another vector that is coding for treatment vs. control. How do I do that?
2. For my model (model) I need to fit a linear model testing for a treatment effect but I don't know how to add that effect into what I have or is that what it is testing in the code I have?

```
    library(car)
    
    treat=rnorm(3, mean = 460, sd = 110)
    treat
    cont=rnorm(3, mean = 415, sd = 110)
    cont
    vect=c(treat, cont)
    vect
    
    nsims = 1000
    
    p.value.saved = coeff.saved = vector()
    
    for (i in 1:nsims) {
      treat=rnorm(3, mean = 460, sd = 110)
      cont=rnorm(3, mean = 415, sd = 110)
      vect=c(treat, cont)
      
      model = glm(treat ~ cont, family = poisson)
      
      p.value.saved[i] = Anova(model)$P[1]
      coeff.saved[i] =  coef(model)
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code is a paired comparison, your questions makes it sound like you want to model `vect ~ is_treat`, i.e. unpaired, which of the two do you need?

Comment: I think you are right, the second one. I think I want vect as the response variable but instead of treat I want it as a function of a vector that is coding treatment vs. control. But that's what I can't figure out how to do. Because vect and treat are not the same length as I have them now.

Comment: Basically I want a vector that has treat and cont in one and then a second vector that codes treat vs cont.

Comment: The second vector should be coding which of the two treatments each value came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (note that you'll get a bunch of warnings for running a poisson regression against continuous data.

```
n <- 3
nsims <- 10
do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(1:nsims, function(.) {
    treat <- rnorm(n, mean = 460, sd = 110)
    cont <- rnorm(n, mean = 415, sd = 110)

    # Instead of vect
    df <- data.frame(
      y = c(treat, cont), 
      x = rep(c("treat", "cont"), each = n)
    )

    # Model the values vs treatment indicator
    model <- glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = poisson)

    # Extract the model's p-value and coefficient of treatment.
    data.frame(p = car::Anova(model)$P, coef = coef(model)[2])
  })
)
```

Comment: That seems right to me!! Is "rerun" supposed to be "return"?

Comment: I've never used the "rerun" function so I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: rerun is not found when I try to run the code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, rerun is a `purrr` function. This can also be done with lapply, see my edit

Comment: A base analogue would be `replicate` so you can `do.call(rbind, replicate(nsims, {<simulation}, simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: I am familiar with lapply so that looks much better! Thank you!

Comment: Do you happen to know if I were to plot the statistical power vs. the number of replicates, would I just plot(y~x)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by statistical power in this context?

Comment: I went ahead and posted a separate question so there was more information so no worries. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The first creates the string and the second bit will combine them. In your example they are both length 3, hence the 3 repetition in rep("trt",3)

```
treat_lab = c(rep("control", 3),rep("trt", 3))
treatment <- cbind(treat_lab,c(treat,cont))
```

Comment: So the second bit (treatment) is just a vector combining treat and cont? Then how would I create another vector coding treat vs cont? For the second part of my linear model. So it would be glm(treatment ~ ____)

Comment: The second vector needs to be coding which of the two treatments each value came from and I believe that would go in the blank.